# How to transfer latest state between threads in rust without using a mutex

Tags: multithreading, rust, real-time, robotics, rust-tokio

I am working on a Rust project where I have two distinct threads that serve specific purposes. One is a real-time thread which interfaces directly with a piece of hardware and maintains strict timing requirements, while the other is a web server thread that provides an API for querying the current state of said hardware.

I need a mechanism through which the web server thread can acquire the most recent state of the hardware from the real-time thread. The challenge here is to avoid the use of mutexes, as the real-time thread cannot afford to be blocked waiting for the mutex.

Here are a few solutions I have considered and their corresponding challenges:

1. `rwlock`: But the writer thread (real-time thread) would need to wait if any reader has a lock on it.
2. Double Buffering: The thread that does the swap needs a mutable reference to the entire struct, which causes borrow checker problems.
3. `mpsc Channel`: If there are no web requests being made, the channel could fill up quickly, leading to wasted memory.

Comment: What data does the state report consist of, exactly? How large is it? That will affect what solutions are feasible.

Comment: @KevinReid It's a struct representing all the states aggregated from all parts of a robot, about 10 or so f32s and some booleans some enums

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap) crate, that provides the [`ArcSwap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/latest/arc_swap/type.ArcSwap.html) type (and related types): an `Arc` that can be replaced and loaded in a lock-free fashion.

Comment: The documentation said it's meant for "often read and seldom updated" data, which sounds like the opposite of my use case. 


Looking at the source code, it looks like `ArcSwap::store()` calls `ArcStore::swap()` which calls `wait_for_readers`, which sounds like it'll block.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a [`ring channel`](https://docs.rs/ring-channel/latest/ring_channel/index.html) with size 1, which uses a [`AtomicCell<Option<Box<T>>>`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/atomic/struct.AtomicCell.html) from [`crossbeaml`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/index.html) underneath.

The real-time thread can `send()` into the channel, which is atomic and lock-free. Then the web thread can `recv()` from the channel, or if there's nothing in the channel, continue using the last read value.